# window.stop() through execute_script() is not working in chromedriver but works in geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I try to stop the browser when it takes too long to load. For this I use `window.stop();` method via selenium `execute_script()`

**Chrome** Fails

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capa)

driver.get('http://deelay.me/15000/http://httpbin.org/ip') #loads a page after 15 seconds

driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
```

Though we get control over the browser object quickly i.e `driver` due to `pageLoadStrategy` -> None; we can't make much use of it.
i.e the script executes only after the page is loaded completely blocking 15seconds.

No errors or exception, it just hangs without returning the control.

> Chromium 73.0.3683.75 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04
>
> ChromeDriver 2.43.600233 (523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d)
>
> Python selenium 3.14.1

Compared to this the **Firefox** browser promptly executes the script and stops loading the page.

**Firefox** Passes

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


capa = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=capa)

driver.get('http://deelay.me/15000/http://httpbin.org/ip') #loads a page after 15 seconds

driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
```

Here not only could we stop the execution we can also call new URL, which is not possible in chrome.

> Firefox 66.0.1
>
> Geckodriver 0.23.0 ( 2018-10-04)
>
> Python selenium 3.14.1

Is this the intended behavior or a bug. Anything not properly carried out from my side?

Comment: Why do you need to _stop the browser_? What is your usecase all about?

Comment: @DebanjanB when i test my site, i keep a limit of how long it must take. this is done by `socket` timeout. when socket throws exception, I will stop the loading and report.

Comment: In that case on `socket timeout` catch the exception and move out of `try-catch{}` scope, why would you still keep engaged with the dying browser instance?

Comment: @DebanjanB so that i can test other link in same browser?
I believe both chrome and firefox could be nearly ideal in the kind of behavior a browser must posses. When i spotted this I thought I must ask the pros if this is the intended behavior or a bug and how to work around?

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue seems to be regarding the implementation of **`window.stop();`** command using `execute_script()`.

Till *ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6*, *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome* was **OSS** compliant and implemented the [JSON wire protocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol). However with the availability of *ChromeDriver v75.0.3770.8*, *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome* now runs in [**W3C standard**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) compliant mode by **default**.

---

### Solution

If you are expecting *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome* to behave just like *GeckoDriver* and *Firefox*, you have to start using **ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8** and the other matching binaries.

---

### Arrival of ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8

John Chen (Owner - chromedriver) recently have announced that:

> We are happy to announce that ChromeDriver version 75.0.3770.8 has been released, and available at the [ChromeDriver Downloads site](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). This version of ChromeDriver is intended for users of upcoming Beta release of Chrome version 75.
>
> In this new release, the most noticeable change is ChromeDriver now runs in [W3C standard](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) compliant mode by default. The legacy [JSON wire protocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) is still supported, but will be removed sometime in the future.
>
> Please see the [release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/notes.txt) for other changes included in this release.

---

### Snapshot of Email from John Chen

[image: ChromeDriver75]

Comment: while this is all true, it doesn't answer the question whatsoever.  what does the w3c compliance have to do with executing window.stop via javascript?

Comment: Ok i will check out the newer versions and let you know if they works similarly, specifically the `window.stop()`. Thanks